# Android Battery information, without registering broadcast receiver?

Tags: android

Is there any way to use `BatteryManager`(or something similar) to get information about the battery charge level and state WITHOUT registering a broadcast receiver??

I basically want to send battery info (amongst other things) to my server upon the push of a button. Just once. Is this possible??

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On some likely `Context` (e.g., the `Activity` with the button in question), call:

```
Intent i=registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

The `Intent` you get back will be the last broadcast for this action, as `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` is a sticky broadcast. You would then read the extras out of the returned `Intent`, as if you had received it via a `BroadcastReceiver`. However, since you are passing `null` as the receiver, you are not registering to receive broadcasts over time.